# Adding secondary IP to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, centos7, amazon-elastic-ip

I've got two servers with two two EIPs and I've done a migration from one to the other and now want one of the EC2s to manage both EIPs till I upgrade it.

I've [followed the instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html#assignIP-existing) to add it and it displays in the console however no additional network interface comes up using `netstat -i` and when I assign the EIP to the private IP the server doesn't respond.

I added the additional routes, rules and configs but when I try to restart the network service it fails stating eth1 does not seem to be present.

Once I add the additional private IP to the network interface should it show up with `netstat -i`? Am I doing the right thing for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need an additional network interface. Just create a subinterface with the second IP. Example, for Debian/Ubuntu ( /etc/network/inteface):

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask x.x.x.x
```